# Android application doesn't run with mvn

Tags: android, windows, maven, android-emulator

I built and deployed a android application successful, but when I execute the command `mvn android:run -Dandroid:device=emulator` in a command line window, the Android application can't be run in the emulator.

I don't know why, and who can give me some help?

I am using Windows 7, mvn 3.0.4, android platform 4.0.3.

Comment: What do you mean by can't be run? What type of error message do you get

Comment: on android phone, when you click on a app, the app will run, is right? for example: after you click on google map app on android phone, the google map app will run on the front.                when i android:run in cmd, the app on android phone not run（the app had installed on phone）.